# How to estimate cost/time of unloading data from Snowflake to S3?

Tags: amazon-web-services, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I've tried going through the `Snowflake documentation`, also `AWS's` and the rest of the internet in general, and I just can't get a useful answer to this.

I need to establish a cost estimate for unloading 750GB of data from `Snowflake AWS US-West` into `S3`, into either the same `AWS` region, or into Europe/London.

If I can't get a direct cost estimate, then an understanding of the bandwidth, how long it would take, and compute resources for e.g. a "Large" virtual warehouse would help.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure if this is the level of detail you need, but it is important to note regarding your question about the size of the warehouse, that the larger the warehouse you use, the faster the data will be unloaded IF you allow the unload to be multiple files.  Snowflake will create a file for each thread that it is allowed to use on the warehouse (8 per node, 1 node = XSMALL).  So, if you want the data out in the most efficient manner (FAST + Cost), use a larger warehouse.

As for the region, if you land it in the same region as your Snowflake instance, you will not be charged any egress for pulling data out of your region.  If you land into Europe/London, then Snowflake will pass-through the costs that AWS will charge you for the cross-region egress.  There is a price chart for this at: https://www.snowflake.com/pricing/pricing-guide/

Answer (score 0):

There are two kind of costs involved.

1. Data transfer costs: 
   https://www.snowflake.com/pricing/pricing-guide/ has a DataTransfer price list.
   I kindly refer to that page.
2. Computing costs for unloading data: 
   It is estimated that for 672GB you need around 2 credits. 
   So I assume that for 750GB you will need 3 credits.
   And it will take around 23 minutes.

Comment: Can I ask where your calculations for point 2 come from please? Presumably it depends where you're unloading to/from e.g. just to Staging, or to AWS same region, AWS other region, or even local download?